# How can I use APISetu to get documents from DigiLocker

Tags: javascript, java, callback, webhooks

I am trying to integrate [DigiLocker](https://www.digilocker.gov.in/) APISs into my program. I am confused about lots of things, I need stepwise details to use DigiLocker to perform the following tasks:

- First open DigiLocker page for user registration
- When user registers, ask consent for required documents (Aadhar and driving license)
- After that collect the document and store in my database and my website should respond with a 'success' response

I finished successfully the first two tasks using the generated API key from API Setu partners and I am also sure that it is calling the callback from the API after the consent is given.

But I have no idea from where that callback API is coming. I can also change how I invoke the API, but I am not sure how can I alter it to get the desired files.